# How to use ViewPager with CursorLoader?

Tags: android

I show a set of fragments in ViewPager. Each fragment uses CursorLoader to upload data in list view. 
The issue is that all fragments use **the same** Uri (and obviously a token) and we all known that we can have only one CursorLoader per Activity. It means that we need separate different calls of CursorLoader by token. In my case token always the same and all three fragmetns in - one focused and two from left and right side - use the last result of CursorLoader.

How we can use CursorLoader in ViewPAger if don;t have a chance to change a token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use cursor loader from fragment rather then from activity.

It is true that cursor loader is the one, but it the one per activity or fragment. If you call cursor loader from parent activity the calls to the same uri are causes of collision. Just invoke cursor loader from fragment.